# Rails devise with gmail errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer

I'm currently working on an application with a mailer system. It was working fine, sending a welcome email and sending instructions to reset password, but now and only when I try to send reset instructions I have this error.

```
ArgumentError (SMTP From address may not be blank: nil):
```

I'm using a custom domain like so `noreply@mycustomdomain.com`
And here is my configuration

**development.rb**

```
 config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
 config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }

 config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
 config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
     address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
     port: '587',
     domain: 'gmail.com',
     authentication: :plain,
     enable_starttls_auto: true,
     user_name: Rails.application.secrets.mailer_username,
     password: Rails.application.secrets.mailer_password
}
```

Any idea ?

**Edit**

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'noreply@mycustomdomain.com'

  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url = 'http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in'
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Bienvenue')
  end

  def generate_new_password_email
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    user.send_reset_password_instructions
  end

  def reset_password; end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, and the reason behind that was i working in *development* but my mailer was searching the smtp_settings in the *production*, so to solve the issue you can change the mailer settings or you can copy the same smtp_settings into production.

Answer (score 7):

You could try setting *:from* in your config, using the *default_option* like this,

```
config.action_mailer.default_options = { from: 'noreply@mycustomdomain.com' }
```

Comment: this is 10 months old

Comment: Came here with that error from test suite (rspec): turned out that I didn't add `default_options` to `config/environments/test.rb` — fixed it. Thanks! @Manspider, it's now more than 2 years old, but still helpful

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you don't have a `From` header in your email. A good practice would be to put the following line into your `ApplicationMailer`:

```
class ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'noreply@mycustomdomain.com'

  # ...
end
```

To override this in your inheriting mailers, simply declare the same statement. To override it in individual mail methods, put it into the `mail` call like so:

```
def new_message(user, message)
  mail(
    to: user.email,
    subject: "New message from #{message.sender.name}",
    from: message.sender.email
  )
end
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I do have a `default from` set to the correct address in my mailer. Also the mail is send by Devise as it is a mail to reset a password. It worked for a time without having to override anything so the problem is somewhere else maybe.

Comment: @LRP it's in devise.rb. Need something like this:   config.mailer_sender = ENV['SMTP_USERNAME']

Answer (score 2):

In devise.rb `config.mailer_sender = 'please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com'` had been commented.
Config.mailer_sender was never initialized and so always nil even if I set it with `default from:`

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same problem. My solution was, I edited `config/initializers/devise.rb` changed a line from `config.mailer_sender = 'please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com'`
 to `config.mailer_sender = ENV["default_from_email"]`